# Regarding suitable Regression Model

Tags: pandas, dataframe, regression, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression

I'm working on a dataset with 5 dependent parameters and one independent parameter. I've loaded the data, made two layers x and y, used sigmoid function but accuracy is showing 0. Can anyone help me in providing me the code for the prediction. Please provide your mail id and I'll provide you the code and dataset

Comment: StackOverflow is not a work request forum. There's probably other places like that, but here you need to include all the necessary information in your question, including what you have done so far, and what is the actual problem you're having

Comment: import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv("/content/Halli_4.csv")
df.head()